# Is it okay to calculate the validation loss over batches instead of the whole validation set for speed purposes?

Tags: machine-learning, loss, batch-learning, validation-loss

I have about 2000 items in my validation set, would it be reasonable to calculate the loss/error after each epoch on just a subset instead of the whole set, if calculating the whole dataset is very slow?

Would taking random mini-batches to calculate loss be a good idea as your network wouldn't have a constant set? Should I just shrink the size of my validation set?

Comment: I would also suggest that you explain a little bit the model you're using, how much time it takes to compute the validation loss and what is the task you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you intended to write compute the *evaluation metric* over the validation set in batches; you do not compute **loss** over the validation set!

That is quite a standard practice in many academic implementations (*because, when the validation set is large enough, the memory will be a constraint*), however, be sure to take the average of the values over all the batches. Using a K-fold setup will increase the confidence in the reported values.